# What is the book - a story of an investigator sent to a city to find out what is going on but is not allowed to discuss anything?

Tags: story-identification

A man is sent to a City far away, in a mountain area, where he has to investigate something but is not allowed to discuss his work with others.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! What are the science fiction or fantasy elements of this story? If there are no such elements this is off-topic.

Comment: Also, please be sure to take the [tour] and read through the [FAQ] to better understand how this site works.

Comment: We really need more details here. Is this a city in a recognizable country? Ditto for the mountain area? Do you know what sort of thing he's investigating? When did you read this? Was it a hardback? Paperback? EBook? Papyrus scroll? What language was it in?

Answer (score 2):

This is very little to go on, but... it *could* be Lou Cameron's *[Cybernia](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5996282-cybernia)* (1972).

> The town of terror Cybernia. Ross MacLean was a computer expert. One of those bright guys with a head for pure logic. Machines break down once in a while, and he could set them straight in no time. That's why he was going to Cybernia.
> Cybernia was a new community - a community of tomorrow. It was fully modernized and automated, run by a fantastic computer. But the computer was acting strangely. At least that's what Ed Morton, town manager, said when he called in MacLean.
>
> It was getting bigger. It was controlling things it was never programmed to control.
>
> Then suddenly it started killing people.

- investigator to a city - check
- mountain area - check
- far away - not quite (it is in commuting range from New York)
- can't discuss with others - check, somewhat